# How to test if a *void pointer points to NSObject in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, testing, nsobject, void-pointers

I would like to know witch is the best practice to test if void pointer is actually an objective C object pointer (NSObject*)...

```
- (id)initWithExecPath:(NSString*)executePath withArgs:(NSArray*)args identifier:(NSString*)identifierString contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo {

// I would like to check here if contextInfo is an NSObject

}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post from the [CocoaWithLove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/testing-if-arbitrary-pointer-is-valid.html) site:

> In this post, I look at an approach for testing if an arbitrary
>   pointer is a pointer to a valid Objective-C object. The result from
>   the test is not absolutely accurate and can interfere with gdb
>   debugging if the pointer isn't a valid memory location, so this is not
>   something you'd want to do often (and certainly not in production
>   code). But it can be a handy debugging tool for when you're staring
>   blindly at memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: should be http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/testing-if-arbitrary-pointer-is-valid.html

Comment: Thank you for your posts, already checked this, wondering if there was a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that no you can't provide a general test for "is an Objective-C object".  Any such test would have to examine the internal structure of an object and is therefore fragile by definition.  There is also the possibility of being handed a random piece of memory that looks like an Objective-C object but isn't.  e.g. a recently deallocated object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to determine this. Also, any API that takes a context pointer shouldn't care what it is or what it points to, it shouldn't do anything with it other than pass it back to the caller as context.

Perhaps you are asking the wrong question; what exactly do you want to do once you know it is an NSObject?

Comment: xmm, I agree but... well this method is initializing an NSThread. When I pass a contextInfo pointer, how to make sure that the object it points to, is still there (not deallocated) when the NSThread has finished executing? (The NSThread is calling a delegate method to inform its delegate that is has finished passing the contextInfo back). So I thought to retain it if it's an NSObject - Note that it can be just an *int or *char. Of course I could just use 2 parameters (id and *void) in this method. Just looking for alternatives, etc :). Thanks!